# How to check if the first character of a string is number in bash?

Tags: xml, regex, bash, shell

I am writing an xml element in bash. I need to replace some strings which will start with numbers into something that starts with an character, so it is a valid XML tag (remember xml tags cannot start with alpha numeric characters).

For Example,

```
  str = 192.16.76.52,1001
```

which is not a valid xml tag, i.e i cannot do

```
<192.16.76.52,1001>
.....
</192.16.76.52,1001>
```

So, I am planning to detect if it is a number and replace it with something like

```
IP192.16.76.52
```

I know I can do it with IFS, but it might take long time and extra code.

Since you know the main problem, feel free to comment or offer suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to use '.' in the element name.

Comment: oh I see.... I dont think I will ever parse the xml file.... but do you think, it will affect the XML file format?

Comment: Yeah, I removed it, also I need to remove comma here....

Comment: which I did but str=$(echo $str | cut -d /, -f 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RHS of `=` in `[[` takes a glob pattern.

```
$ [[ 123 = [0-9]* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ foo = [0-9]* ]] ; echo $?
1
```